# Error in playing multichannel audio at different instances?

Tags: audio, gstreamer, alsa

I am trying to play 2 channels in which audio in one and silence in other channel is being played.

```
$ gst-launch \
    interleave name=i ! alsasink
    filesrc location=/home/test1.mp3 \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert \
        ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! i. \
    audiotestsrc wave=silence \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert \
        ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! volume volume=1.0 ! i.
```

After 10 sec I want to play silence in first and some audio in the second channel.

```
$ gst-launch \
    interleave name=i ! alsasink \
    audiotestsrc wave=silence \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert \
        ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! i. \
    filesrc location=/home/test2.mp3 \
        ! decodebin ! audioconvert \
        ! audio/x-raw-int,channels=1 ! volume volume=1.0 ! i.
```

This can be done on PC's side, while playing these pipeline in two different terminals or making one of them run in background. But when I am playing one pipeline on am335x board and trying to play the other one, its something like this:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
ERROR: Pipeline doesn't want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSink:alsasink0: Could not open audio device for playback. 
Device is being used by another application.
Additional debug info:
gstalsasink.c(697): gst_alsasink_open (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSink:alsasink0:
Device 'default' is busy
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

when we check in gstalsasink.c it is calling snd_pcm_open in non-blocking mode .

```
CHECK (snd_pcm_open (&alsa->handle, alsa->device, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK,
      SND_PCM_NONBLOCK), open_error);
```

Then why its blocking other events to use the audio device?

Can anyone suggest me what to do for the target side ,since PC side alsasink is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

could there be a little delay for closing the alsa device on your embedded hardware. Check with fuser which process has it still open. Also consider using gnonlin for developing a sequential playback of streams. This will reuse the existing audio sink.

Comment: gnonlin will not satisfy my requirement,because its not definite in real time scenario that after what time ,the second pipeline should be played.Its a random upcoming situation where may be the silenced channel need to be used for playing another audio.                     And how its fine using same pipelines in PC side while its throwing errors on target board .

Comment: okay, so the use case is more like a radio-stream, where you want to overdub an announcement?

Comment: yes.Its like if only one audio is being broadcasted over first channel,and we want to start another announcement over the second channel which was silent till now, then error I am getting is "device busy".

Comment: From alsasink hw access is in non blocking mode.From driver's side how to check its opening in non blocking mode.

Comment: In that case, eitehr use dmix on the alsa side or one alsasink instance on the gstreamer side an mix the streams using adder inside the gstreamer pipeline.

Comment: I am not very clear .Can you elaborate? Dmix also if we use, it mixes 2 songs in one terminal.But when I am opening in two other terminals on my board then its telling "aplay: main:660: audio open error: Device or resource busy".                                 I was just going through code gstalsasink.c .Its calling snd_pcm_open in NON BLOCKING MODE.What does this mean?